# How to get the following Linux performance parameters?

Tags: linux, performance, proc

How to get the following performance parameters on Linux, especially per-CPU ? Is there any api to get these params like kstat on Solaris and pstat on HPUX ?

Number Cross-CPU calls, 
Number of Device interrupts, 
Number of interrupts as threads (below clock), 
Number of context switches, 
Number of involuntary context switches, 
Number of cpu migrations by threads, 
Number of failed mutex enters (adaptive), 
Number of tries to acquire rw lock , 
Number of system calls,

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Have you looked at [`mpstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpstat) and its internals? Your list appear to be copied from Solaris mpstat, but not all data are provided by Linux Kernel (i.e. lock stats)

Comment: I need some api or proc files where they reside.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check in Ctrap (link:http://search.cpan.org/~bloonix/Sys-Statistics-Linux-0.66/lib/Sys/Statistics/Linux/Processes.pm and http://search.cpan.org/~bloonix/Sys-Statistics-Linux-0.66/lib/Sys/Statistics/Linux/CpuStats.pm)
2. Dtrace for linux might be worth to try  (https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux)

Comment: Parameters I want are ...Number Cross-CPU calls, Number of Device interrupts, Number of interrupts as threads (below clock), Number of context switches, Number of involuntary context switches, Number of cpu migrations by threads, Number of failed mutex enters (adaptive), Number of tries to acquire rw lock , Number of system calls,